# Simple homomorphic crypto for 32-bit integers

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I'm looking for a simple way to perform homomorphic crypto on 32-bit integers. My only requirement is that I can add and subtract from the plaintext value without actually decrypting it. The crypto need not be particularly strong - the implementation is designed to be a deterrent rather than something more concrete.

Are there any simple algorithms to do such a thing? I'm looking for something that's easy to understand and implement.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is the Pallier cryptosystem, which is additively homomorphic. But I would also be interested in lightweight schemes to achieve this. The small 32-bit space might be a problem for public key schemes, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "32-bit integer". If you want to add *integers* which will never exceed the range -2<sup>31</sup>..2<sup>31</sup>-1 (i.e. integers which fit in 32 bits), then [Paillier cryptosystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem) will be fine. It uses mathematics which can be viewed as "slightly complex" so you could also rely on a simpler [ElGamal encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption). With ElGamal, you do not add; you *multiply*. So you would have to represent integer value *x* with value *g<sup>x</sup>*, and, upon decryption, you would have to solve the discrete logarithm, which can be done with cost about 2<sup>16</sup> if you are sure that the exponent resides in a 32-bit range (2<sup>32</sup> is low enough that this can practically be sped up a lot with precomputed tables; e.g., store hashes of all *g<sup>y</sup>* where *y* is a multiple of 2<sup>12</sup>: you only need to store a million hash values, and you do the discrete log step in an average of two thousands multiplications and hashing).

If by "32-bit integer" you mean *modular* integers, which "wrap around" at 32 bits, then things become much more complex. You could choose the group parameters for ElGamal such that the generator *g* has order 2<sup>32</sup> exactly, but security would have been quite nullified in the process. It would deter only low-grade attackers who indiscriminately balk at mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

I have made good experiences with Paillier.
You will find several existing implementations for it on the net.
Personally I'm using an enhanced version of this one:
[The Homomorphic Encryption Project](http://code.google.com/p/thep/)
The offered standard package is working fine and above all well documented. Homomorphic operations are completely transparent - you don't need to know anything about it.
There is just a catch with negative numbers but you will find a solution in the FAQ.